# First order higher degree nonlinear ODE $y=xp^{2}+p$ with $p=dy/dx$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I've got the equation:
$$y = xp^2 + p$$
Here, $p = dy/dx$

I've tried all three methods I know, that are solvable for $x, y$ and $p$ but haven't reached the right solution which is supposed to be:

Ans : $$x = (\ln(p) − p + c)(p − 1)^2$$
Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Given that $p$ is a function of $x$, obtaining $x$ as a function of $p$ does not look like an answer to me. You are only chasing your own tail if you do this.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate the given differential with respect to $x$, we get
$\frac{dy}{dx}= 2xp\frac{dp}{dx}+p^2+\frac{dp}{dx}$. Let $\frac{dy}{dx}=p$ and re-writing the above equation, we have $$\frac{dx}{dp}+\frac{2}{p-1}x=\frac{1}{p(1-p)}.$$ You can solve this  linear equation in $x.$

Comment: You could also go more directly, change to $p$ as independent parameter from the start with $y'(p)=px'(p)$ and thus $px'(p)=p^2x'(p)+2px+1$.

Comment: Your formal manipulations ca be misleading, and even wrong: since $p = \frac {\mathrm d y} {\mathrm d x}$, what meaning does $\frac {\mathrm d x} {\mathrm d p}$ have? And again, since $p$ is a function of $x$, how can you say that the equation that you obtain is linear in $x$?

Comment: @AlexM. : The larger frame is to consider the surface $y=xp^2+p$ in the $(x,y,p)$ space, and in its tangent space $ker(-dy+p^2\,dx+2px\,dp+dp)$ the lines with $dy=p\,dx$ and then the curves that are tangent to this line bundle. On some subset the coordinate $p$ can serve as independent parameter of these curves.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: I agree that this solution can be given some rigorous meaning, and this would probably involve the implicit function theorem or the local inversion theorem. In any case, there is significantly more to say than the very basic formal manipulations performed in the above post. In fact, I bet that its author never even realised the complexity hidden behind his answer.

Comment: @AlexM. I think the approach the solution is correct. Here we have $y=y(x)$ and the change of variables $p=dy/dx$ give by chain rule $(dp/dx)(dx/dp)=1$ then $dx/dp=1/(dx/dp)$. All this that seems to clear things up is well justified by the local inversion theorem and the implicit function theorem. If the OP is in a basic differential equations course maybe he/she is by now only just familiar with the operational side of differential equations, I judge this based on the OP's post.

Comment: Moreover the ODE here we can solve by integrating factor $(p-1)^{2}$ and solving all we get $x=\frac{\ln |p|-p+c}{(p-1)^{2}}$ which is just (maybe the OP has a typo) the answer given by the OP. Of course this is just my observation as far as I can understand.

Comment: @AlexM.  As I know the complexity of the question.  I guess this would be from the introductory elementary differential equation course.